# Drop Down Box Keeps flickering - JQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, drop-down-menu

I am having difficulty with something really basic. I am trying to implement a drop down box with JQuery and CSS. I can not figure out why my drop down box keeps flickering when I hover over the "Products" link.

Here is a demo of what I am working on. http://174.132.101.73/~ree/header/

I would appreciate any help on this.

### Edit

Well the code can be found by looking at the source code of the link I gave. The main part you might need that displays/hides the drop-down box is this, alongside CSS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('li.headlink').hover(
   function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'block'); },
   function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'none'); });
 });
```

Comment: Could you post the code that displays/hides the drop-down box?

Comment: Oh, and here's a debugging tip: Add a separate debug.css file, which contains a 'shocking' unique background-color for each element. Watching the coloured blocks jostle and jiggle around during document reflow is a great way to see what's going on. If you see that a box moves dramatically, it sometimes helps to see what it lines up against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#header_wrapper` has width fixed at 950px, and `#logo` and `#nav` are floated within it. Since `#logo` is 250px, that leaves 700px for what's in `#nav` (whose elements are also floated).

Everything fits just fine until the 'Products' submenu becomes visible. Then its `.headlink` becomes much wider, due to the extra content, which pushes the overall size of `#nav` to where it is forced down to the next "line", below `#logo`. This is the way floated elements work; they fill up the space horizontally until some block is too big and gets pushed down below the first one.

The flicker results from the fact that `:hover` is no longer active and the submenu gets hidden. Then everything goes back to the way it was. Except that the mouse pointer is still there, and so now `:hover` is active again. Repeat.

I'm not sure how I'd fix it, but that appear to me to be what's wrong. Maybe you could alter the way your elements are nested, or don't float the nav section. For a quick fix, you could change the `#header_wrapper` width to something much bigger, such as 1450px, just to see how the 'Products' submenu is behaving, and work out its kinks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have been tackling this issue for the last 15 minutes and have finally found the ACTUAL solution.

I have coded dropdowns in the past, fine, and was wondering why I was now getting this flickering issue as I was using solid code and timeouts.

Well, I figured out I was using the wrong Jquery event. Do not use the jquery `HOVER` event, instead use the jquery `mouseover` event and `mouseout` event. This will solve the `HOVER` related issues.

Next set up a timeout for hiding and, when showing, clear the timeout and, before hiding, clear the timeout. Set this for however long you want the menu to be there when you scroll out.

If you use the timeout with the hover and you still get flicker, be sure to use `mouseover` event.

```
$(".btn").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    $(this).addClass("hover"); 
    /* can add class, or manually set menu visible, i prefer using CSS class */
}).mouseout(function() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    /* clear timeout in case 2 mouseout events fire at same time */
    this.timeout = setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }, 300));
});
```

This code should be re-usable to ALL drop downs in your page.