# JavaScript dropdown menu flickers when moused over quickly

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, toggle, mouseover

I created a JavaScript dropdown menu but it flickers in a glitchy way when moused over quickly in Safari and Chrome. It's not a problem in Firefox.

I've seen posts on this issue discussing parent/child problems or troubles with hover but I'm not sure they apply. I am brand new to JavaScript, and this is the first code I have ever written, so I didn't really understand the responses.

It's a horizontal menu and each bar has HTML like this...

```
<li>
<a href="#" id="dropMenu3" class="dropMenu" onclick="dropDown3()">Creations</a>
    <div id="dropDiv3" class="dropDiv bar3" onmouseout="hideDiv3()">
    <a href="#">Creations</a>
    <a href="#">Cordie-bot</a>
    <a href="#">Infinity Clock</a>
    <a href="#">Steampunk Hat</a>
    <a href="#">Birdfeeder</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

And JavaScript like this...

```
function dropDown3() {
    document.getElementById("dropDiv1").classList.remove("show");
    document.getElementById("dropDiv2").classList.remove("show");
    document.getElementById("dropDiv3").classList.toggle("show");
    document.getElementById("dropDiv4").classList.remove("show");
    document.getElementById("dropDiv5").classList.remove("show");
}
function hideDiv3(){
    document.getElementById("dropDiv3").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Each div is on top of its menu bar when it's showing so that the mouseout works at the top too, but I had the flickering problem prior to setting it up that way as well.

I'm sure there are much better ways to code this but I don't think there is anything grossly wrong with it. It works just fine except for the flickering. So please let me know if there's some way to fix it. And please keep it simple. I'm a newbie. Also, I do not use jQuery.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using CSS for this?

Comment: I used plenty of CSS to style this website. I didn't include it in the post as I didn't think it relevant. Are you saying there's a way to make a dropdown menu with just CSS? If so is that preferable for some reason? I would be interested to know how that would be done, but I do want to figure this out using JavaScript. My current goal is to learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the questions in your comments. If you're building a dropdown menu with hover it is preferred that it'd be done with CSS since it has better compatibility with old browsers and it's very simple todo vs trying to do it with javascript which can lead to annoyances like the one you're getting.

Here's a simple dropdown menu built with just CSS

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Sub dropdown</li>
      <li>Sub dropdown</li>
      <li>Sub dropdown</li>
      <li>Sub dropdown</li>
      <li>Sub dropdown</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS**

```
.dropdown {
  &:hover {
    .dropdown-menu {
      display: block
    }
  }
  &-menu {
    display: none
  }
}
```

Fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/z9L02p0j/12)

Comment: This was solved by @jaimerump [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567110/drop-down-menu-flickering-except-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

For my fellow JavaScript newbies:

To answer my own question, the easiest way to get rid of that glitchy flicker is to not use JavaScript. The simple solution is to just use CSS and have the menu open as you hover over it. There’s an example at w3schools under CSS dropdowns. The answer provided by Baruch actually uses SCSS which is NOT just CSS, and probably isn’t the best example to offer someone new to web development.

But if you really want your dropdown menu to open with a mouse click, the usual way to achieve that is to use JavaScript. Again, there’s an example at w3schools under Clickable Dropdown. It’s what I started with, but since their example only shows a single dropdown menu, and I wanted multiple menus, I made several changes. That could be the reason I ended up with the flicker issue.

Now, jaimerump did find a way to fix the flicker, which I linked to in my previous comment, but the code uses jQuery, which isn’t JavaScript per se, it’s actually a library of JavaScript code in an external JavaScript file. So if you want to use that code you’ll need to link your page to jQuery.

I’ll figure out how to solve this using JavaScript eventually, but for now I’m taking the easy way out and using CSS and hover.